# How to Group the elements based on attribute value in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

New to XSLT.

Here is the XML.

```
<Resource resource_id="603">
    <Computer full_name="AJAY-2064" remarks="computer key expired."/>
</Resource>
<Resource resource_id="604">
    <Computer full_name="AJAY-2070" remarks="computer key expired."/>
</Resource>
<Resource resource_id="602">
    <Computer full_name="AJAY-1662" remarks="Not a valid key. "/>
</Resource>
```

My Requirement is to Get the unique remarks count and group the name based on remarks.

(i.e)

Computer key expired  Count (2)

AJAY-2064

AJAY-2070

Not a valid key (1)

AJAY-1662

Here is the xsl.

```
<xsl:variable name="license.computer" select="Resource/ManagedComputer"/>

<xsl:key name="keyComputer" match="$license.computer" use="@remarks"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$license.computer[generate-id() =
                    generate-id(key('keyComputer', @remarks)[1])]">
           <xsl:variable name="license.remarks" select="@remarks"/>

           <xsl:for-each select="$license.computer[contains(@remarks,$license.remarks)]">
                                      <xsl:choose>
                                          <xsl:when test="position() mod  2 = 0" >
                                            <tr>
                                                    <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><xsl:value-of select="@full_name"/></td>
                                                    <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><xsl:value-of select="@remarks"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </xsl:when>
                                          <xsl:otherwise>
                                              <tr>
                                                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><xsl:value-of select="@full_name"/></td>
                                                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><xsl:value-of select="@remarks"/></td>
                                              </tr>
                                          </xsl:otherwise>
                                      </xsl:choose>

           </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Provide any workaround if you have. Any debugger to debug xslt ?

Comment: Searching for ""Grouping in XSLT" will produce a lot of hits. The method depends very much on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, which you haven't told us. Your code above is trying to use the XSLT 1.0 technique called "Muenchian grouping", which is fairly mind-boggling for a newcomer, and even for the more experienced. (I think you've copied and modified example code which you don't understand, which is never a good strategy). In XSLT 2.0, it's much simpler because there's a purpose designed instruction, xsl:for-each-group, that does the job.

Comment: Ya. I know. We aren't using XSLT 2.0. Hence, googled for XSLT 1.0 Grouping. And i came up with that procedure.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. The problem is, most times your google will find example code without an explanation of how it works. And if you don't understand how it works, you'll make a mess of changing it. The best way to find out how it works is to buy a book and work through the examples and explanations; or find a good tutorial site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a lot of reasons why it is "not working", although some of them may be due the question not being fully representative of your actual code.

Still, the first issue is with your `license.computer` variable. Assuming this is a global variable, and not within a template that matches `root`, the xpath expression will be relative to the document node, and so is looking for a root element of `Resource`. But I am guessing you have a different root element, so it probably needs to look like this....

```
<xsl:variable name="license.computer" select="//Resource/Computer"/>
```

(Also note your XSLT refers to `ManagedComputer` but your XML sample only show `Computer`)

Next up, is that you are not allowed to use variables in the match condition of a key, so your key should actually look like this

```
<xsl:key name="keyComputer" match="//Resource/Computer" use="@remarks"/>
```

Also worth noting, although it is not actually a problem in your XSLT, but to iterate over the elements in the group, you can replace your inner `xsl:for-each` with this

```
 <xsl:for-each select="key('keyComputer', @remarks)">
```

Try this XSLT
Actually, you could also define it just like this, as you don't need the full xpath expression, unless you want to restrict which `Computer` elements it matches

```
<xsl:key name="keyComputer" match="Computer" use="@remarks"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:variable name="license.computer" select="//Resource/Computer"/>
   <xsl:key name="keyComputer" match="Computer" use="@remarks"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="$license.computer[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyComputer', @remarks)[1])]">      
          <xsl:for-each select="key('keyComputer', @remarks)">
              <xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
                 <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() mod  2 = 0" >#F9F9F9</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>#FFFFFF</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:variable>
              <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="{$bgcolor}"><xsl:value-of select="@full_name"/></td>
                  <td bgcolor="{$bgcolor}"><xsl:value-of select="@remarks"/></td>
             </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also I have re-jigged how it does the background colour of the cells to avoid some code repetition.